# FFMPEG H.264 encoding for HTML5 (and ultimately MPEG-DASH)

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, chromium

I want to convert an MP4 file to an MPEG-DASH video capable of being played through the [DASH-IF HTML5 player](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) on Chrome. I use FFMPEG and MP4Box (from GPAC) to transcode the video and then split it, and keep getting a MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED error on the JavaScript console.

From the (very sparse) information available online (see [this Chromium thread](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408552)), it would appear as though Chrome natively only supports MP4 files with the Constrained Baseline encoding profile, and is very strict on only supporting the "avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2" codecs.

I have tried pretty much everything I can to encode the video from the command line, prior to splitting with MP4Box, with FFMPEG to get an H.264 video encoding with codec profile "avc1.42E01E", but it just keeps giving me "avc1.42C01E". Here's one of the (many) FFMPEG commands I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -y -i Sintel_-_Third_Open_Movie_by_Blender_Foundation.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level:v 30 -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 sintel-recoded.mp4
```

According to the ITU-T standard, sections 7.4.2.1.1 and A2.1-A2.3, a video encoding of "avc1.42E01E" implies constraint flags of 0xE0 (constraint_set flags 0, 1 and 2 are set), whereas "avc1.42C01E" implies constraint flags of 0xC0 (constraint_set flags 0 and 1 are set). The former (0xE0) implies conformance to the Baseline, Main and Extended profiles, whereas the latter (0xC0) implies conformance to only the Baseline and Main profiles.

Apparently, FFMPEG doesn't support the Extended profile for H.264.

Does anyone perhaps have any advice as to how to encode an MP4 file as "avc1.42E01E"? Ideally with FFMPEG, but I am open to using other encoders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging around online for ages, and asking questions in a few places like [GitHub](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/127#issuecomment-75716192), I found that part of the problem was that I wasn't **separating my audio and video prior to segmenting with MP4Box**:

```
# transcode the video to "avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2"
ffmpeg -i Sintel_-_Third_Open_Movie_by_Blender_Foundation.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a libvo_aacenc -profile:v baseline -level:v 13 -g 250 -r 25 -keyint_min 250 -strict experimental -b:a 96k sintel.mp4

# copy out the video only
ffmpeg -i sintel.mp4 -c:v copy -an sintel-video.mp4

# copy out the audio only
ffmpeg -i sintel.mp4 -c:a copy -vn sintel-audio.mp4

# create the MPD manifest with MP4Box, but only with onDemand profile
MP4Box -dash 10000 -profile dashavc264:onDemand -out sintel.mpd sintel-audio.mp4 sintel-video.mp4
```

Plays just fine in Chrome 40.x with the dash.js player. Trouble is, it doesn't work for the `live` MP4Box profile (with separate M4S files for each segment), but it's at least a start.

**Edit**: I've since had a lot more success with preparing and fragmenting my content using castLabs' [DASH.encrypt utility](https://github.com/castlabs/dashencrypt). See [the wiki entries](https://github.com/castlabs/dashencrypt/wiki) for details on how to make use of the utility. Still haven't managed to get my content DASH'd with MP4Box unfortunately.

Comment: I've had success with this tutorial: http://wiki.webmproject.org/adaptive-streaming/instructions-to-playback-adaptive-webm-using-dash

Comment: I've found the same problem in Chrome 42. can you fix this? I already tested in http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/ and this error occurs in console "Error: The browser failed to decode the media content.".

This is my mpd file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/dash/videogular.mpd

Answer (score 2):

If you are not forced to use ffmpeg, I would suggest to give x264 a try, like the guys from [dash-player.com](http://www.dash-player.com) described in one of their [blog posts](http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2014/11/mpeg-dash-content-generation-using-mp4box-and-x264/). From my experience I can definitely say, that Chrome supports far more than one profile for video.

Comment: Thanks very much - I've tried the approach outlined on the link you sent, but it unfortunately still doesn't play in Chrome. The profile of the video generated is "avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2" and, in the JavaScript console, gives the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'streamProcessor' of undefined". This seems more like a bug in the DASH-IF player perhaps?

Comment: You can make sure by testing with other players like [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) on Android or [bitdash](http://www.dash-player.com) - or other browsers which support MSE (IE11 on Win8, Firefox 36/Nightly).

Comment: You can also give some online transcoding service like [bitcodin](http://www.bitcodin.com/) a (free) try, to make sure the content is properly prepared.

Comment: bitcodin gave me an MPD that seems to work just fine, so upon further investigation it seems it's the way I'm generating the MPEG DASH content.